# Variables to include in propensity score matching

Tags: propensity-scores

I want to use propensity score matching to estimate how becoming a mother affect your health.

I define you as a mother, if you in 2006 have children who lives at your home.

Since paneldata i available i am a little confused about when to "measure" the outcome-variable and the variables to include in the propensity score.

If i measure becoming a mother in year 2006, should i then measure the outcome-variable in a year post post-treatment (e.g. 2007)?

And when should i measure the variables to include in the propensity score? Should they be measured in a pre-treatment year (e.g. 2005 or before)?

Best regards